# Qt creator does not work correctly after installing ubuntu sdk

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I installed qt-sdk before installing ubuntu-sdk on ubuntu 12.04. When the Develop, Examples, or Tutorials link on the welcome page is clicked it creates inactive windows and cannot close it normally. Also the help contents are overlapped with images and so it is very difficult to read. Any solutions?

Comment: what is the version of the Qt SDK that you've installed?

Comment: @Projjol Its the latest that comes with Ubuntu SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Qt Creator error. I have the same problem, but the only solution is to click back on the main window. This problem is something the you should take to the developers of Qt Creator. It is a problem that you might have to just ignore. I know it is annoying, trust me.

Good Luck,
Brooks Rady